# Check Constraint in Oracle

Tags: oracle, constraints

I have been struggling to figure out a way to insert check such that it won't allow payment date to be earlier than the invoice date. basically, I have two table: invoice and payment. so I want a check constraint to enter into payment a date that is before the purchase date in invoice table. The invoice_id in Invoice table is a FK in payment table. Any help?

Comment: You can use trigger for same.

Comment: Use Before Insert and check the dates by selecting and comparing them with each other so u can make decision on inserting

Answer (score 3):

A check constraint can only look at columns on the table it is defined on.

You'll need to use a TRIGGER to do this.

Answer (score 2):

One approach might be to duplicate the purchase date in the payment table, add a second unique constraint over the combination of invoice_id + purchase date, then modify the FK constraint to include it. Then, you can have your row-level constraint. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE invoices
( invoice_id    NUMBER NOT NULL
, purchase_date DATE NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT invoice_pk PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id)
, CONSTRAINT invoice_uk UNIQUE (invoice_id, purchase_date)
);

CREATE TABLE payments
( payment_id    NUMBER NOT NULL
, invoice_id    NUMBER NOT NULL
, purchase_date DATE NOT NULL
, payment_date  DATE NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT payment_pk PRIMARY KEY (payment_id)
, CONSTRAINT payment_invoice_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id, purchase_date)
    REFERENCES invoices (invoice_id, purchase_date)
, CONSTRAINT payment_date_ck
    CHECK (payment_date >= purchase_date)
);
```

Downside: updating invoices.purchase_date becomes a bit tricky.